# SQLAlchemy - using column in LIKE

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to do this

```
select x.name, y.name, y.info
from tag x
join tag y
on y.info like '%#' || x.name || '#%';
```

with SQLAlchemy? I found examples using LIKE, but only with literals (from the SQL point of view).

Comment: If you cannot find a solution, remember that you can always pass raw SQL queries to a SQLAlchemy connection object.

Comment: I know, but I do not want to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session.query(x).join(y).filter("y.info LIKE '%#'||x.name||'#%'").all()
```